# Google Sheets formula designed to check another column does not give error but does not work

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working on a formula in Google Sheets that will autofill the region based on the supervisor or office manager of a request. I've got the formula working for the supervisor column but I attempted to modify it to include the office manager with a nested if statement. This is the full formula.

```
=ArrayFormula(IFNA(VLOOKUP(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(AD4:AD,Max(IF(ISBLANK(AD4:AD), IF(ISBLANK(AC4:AC), 0, ROW(AC4:AC)),ROW(AD4:AD)))-3,1),'Supvr List'!$A$32:$B$76,2,0),))
```

originally the formula looked like this

```
=ArrayFormula(IFNA(VLOOKUP(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(AD4:AD,Max(IF(ISBLANK(AD4:AD), 0,ROW(AD4:AD)))-3,1),'Supvr List'!$A$32:$B$76,2,0),))
```

My thinking was that if ISBLANK(AD4:AD) is true I can nest another if statement that does the same thing for the AC column. Right now it does not check the AC column and if you try to set the region manually it returns a !REF error.

Supervisor Column - AD
Office Manager Column - AC
Region Column - AB

Source of Supervisor/Office Manager information ("Supvr List" tab): A32:B76

I appreciate any assistance with this. Thanks!

test sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HV3K9-bHZjH1we2855ilRN0tsOYHKAJcYgtfcNI8Nz8/edit?usp=sharing

Formula starts in AB4

Comment: Please provide a sample data we can work on for us to be able to test the formula. A copy of the sheet with no confidential data would be good.

Comment: @NaziA Should I export it as an excel worksheet? I can't link to my business drive.

Comment: You can create a google sheet and set it to public then have the link in your post.

Comment: Please see [how to share a sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/138382/how-to-share-a-google-sheets-demo-spreadsheet/138383#138383)

Comment: @NaziA Ok added the link in the post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The sheet is still not accessible, can you provide "anyone with the link" access?

Comment: @NaziA not sure why its not working but I did it again, let me know if it works now. Thanks

Comment: I have provided a different solution below, feel free to check @Abangyarudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little different from yours, but the idea of my solution was to check both values (prioritizing `AC`, then `AD`). If both have no values, then leave as blank.

#### Formula:

- `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(IF(ISBLANK(AC4:AC), AD4:AD, AC4:AC), 'Supvr List'!$A$32:$B$76,2,0), ""))`

#### Behavior:

- get `AC` if it has value, else get `AD`
- `VLOOKUP` to get the region. If it returned NA (both `AC` and `AD` are blank), then leave as blank.

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- This doesn't consider the difference in region if both values are different. It always assumes `AC` holds the correct region, thus prioritizing it in the condition. It only gets `AD` if `AC` is blank.

Comment: Thank you for all your work on this but I wanted it to check AC when AD does not have a value. As my current formula only works if there is a value in AD. Most rows will have values in both. Is there a way around this issue?

Comment: @Abangyarudo, if both are present, what value is to be prioritized, AC or AD?

Comment: theoretically it should both lead to the same conclusion but I guess the office manager(AC). Thank you again for your hard work on this.

Comment: I have modified my answer @Abangyarudo, kindly check.